# StyleCop on Azure Pipeline dotnet publish, The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: pipeline, stylecop

I keep getting the following error on the pipeline when trying to do "dotnet publish".
I'm trying to run this on an ubuntu environment.

[Error from Azure pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uRSK.png)

This is the full error line:

/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/stylecop.msbuild/6.2.0/build/StyleCop.MSBuild.targets(101,5): error MSB4062: The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly /home/vsts/.nuget/packages/stylecop.msbuild/6.2.0/build/../tools/StyleCop.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/MyServiceManager.NotificationService.API/MyServiceManager.NotificationService.API.csproj]

Any idea what's up with StyleCop?

Build on local machine is fine.
Build on Azure pipeline breaks.

Tried changing StyleCop.MSBuild versions.
Tried changing to MSBuild instead of "dotnet" command